# When to use « si légère soit-elle » and when to use « aussi légère soit-elle »

Tags: expressions

> Je m’interroge sur la différence entre les trois, que ce soit celle de sens ou de registre, **si légère soit-elle**. Ou est-ce qu’ils sont interchangeables l'un avec l'autre ?

Am I correct in assuming that « aussi légère soit-elle » cannot be used in this specific sentence?

> (x) ? : Je m’interroge sur la différence entre les trois, que ce soit celle de sens ou de registre, **aussi légère soit-elle**.

I wonder if « si légère soit-elle » is only fit for use in a question or a « je me demande si ... » sentence, with the meaning of "no matter how subtle it is" or "**even if** it is very subtle".

Should « aussi légère soit-elle », on the other hand, be used only in an affirmative sentence, with the meaning of "as subtle as it may be", "however subtle it may be", or "**even though** it is very subtle", as in:

> Il existe bien une différence de sens entre les trois, **aussi légère soit-elle**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- *Si légère soit-elle* cannot be a question.
  "si" here is a compromise/concession mark, but not a conditional.

If you want to ask something, predecessing by a condition, you would say, for instance "Si elle était légère, est-ce qu'il voudrait l'acheter ?" or "*Je me demande si elle était légère, est-ce qu'il voudrait l'acheter* ?"

-

But here, it's a compromise, like in "*Aussi légère soit-elle*".

Bien que grammaticalement, il n'y ait pas trop de différences, je trouve qu'il y a une très subtile différence de sens entre "*si légère soit-elle*" est "*aussi légère soit-elle*", mais ça, c'est un autre débat...

- *Léger* et *légère* don't mean subtle. Subtle is subtile.

Ex:
*Si subtile soit ce roman, je lui trouve beaucoup d'intérêt*.

*Aussi subtile soit cette différence, je peux tout de même la ressentir.*

Comment: Do you have an example with "*aussi légère soit-elle*" is in a question ?

Comment: Non, c'est comme pour "si légère soit-elle" ce n'est pas possible. Sauf si on le tourne autrement.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there is absolutely no difference, in this context, between **si**, **aussi** and **quelque**. I would say that **aussi** is the most common (by a slight margin) and that **quelque** is very formal and rare nowadays. Except this, there are all interchangeable in all affirmative, negative and interrogative sentences I can think of.